# How to create a 3D Map using vb.net in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to create a 3D map using vb.net in an excel sheet using data in it.

I have the data already printed in the excel, but I do not find the option to create the 3D map

```vb
Private Sub rellenarMapa(mapa As Excel._Worksheet, hojaPrincipal As Excel._Worksheet, libro As Excel._Workbook)
        mapa.Name = "Mapa de localizaciones"

        Dim ssql = "SELECT 
                        nomcial, 
                        latitud, 
                        longitud 
                    FROM rc_location_log 
                    WHERE 
                        created >= '" & fechaInicial & "' AND 
                        created <= '" & fechaFinal & "' 
                    ORDER BY created DESC"

        Dim rsComerciales As New Recordset
        db.CommandTimeout = 0
        rsComerciales.Open(ssql, db)

        If rsComerciales.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Dim arrayCordenadas(rsComerciales.RecordCount, 3)

            arrayCordenadas(0, 0) = "Nombre Comercial"
            arrayCordenadas(0, 1) = "Latitud"
            arrayCordenadas(0, 2) = "Longitud"

            Dim indexActual = 1
            While Not rsComerciales.EOF
                arrayCordenadas(indexActual, 0) = rsComerciales.Fields("nomcial").Value
                arrayCordenadas(indexActual, 1) = rsComerciales.Fields("latitud").Value
                arrayCordenadas(indexActual, 2) = rsComerciales.Fields("longitud").Value

                indexActual += 1
                rsComerciales.MoveNext()
            End While

            Dim rango As Excel.Range

            'Indico en que rango estara la informacion
            With mapa
                rango = .Range(.Cells(1, 1),
                .Cells(arrayCordenadas.GetLength(0) + 1,
                arrayCordenadas.GetLength(1)))
            End With

            rango.Value2 = arrayCordenadas

        End If
    End Sub
```

I would like to use that data to create a 3D map.

Comment: With your data in Excel, record a VBA macro while manually creating the 3D map that you want. Look at the resulting recorded macro. This will tell you all the Excel objects and their properties to use to create the 3D map. From that, it should be easy to write the equivalent VB.NET code.

Comment: It doesn't record the creation of the 3D map. It only records the selection of the data.

Comment: What Excel chart do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
The way I'm doing it is by having template excel as a base with a power pivot table by default. This way i only need to paste my data in the table, this way the user only has to update the data in the 3D map.

[The template for the power pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZxz4.png)

[This is an example of how the 3D map will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82BJA.jpg)